# User Management - SQL Server Built in vs Custom User List

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I'm just starting to spec out a project that will be a fairly advanced DB with a fairly simple MVC front end, accessible over the internet, I'm unsure of how to handle users, I can see two options:

**Option 1** - Use SQL Servers in-built Logins/Users to handle user authentication and use the in-built user access to control who can access what (almost everything will be selects or stored procs).

**Option 2** - Use my own list of users (with hashed salted passwords) and my own access control list (possibly using proc name and `OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)` passed to another proc) and do all writes/reads of the DB through an application profile with access to all procedures/views.

I've searched but can't find any reasons I should pick one over the other, can anyone share a link or provide reasons why one is better that the other (or if there are glaring issues with both)?

If you need any more details please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If using SQL authentication (Option 1 for each user) via a connection pool, you're going to get comparatively poor performance. You'll get pooling for each user, but that could still mean 100's or 1000's of connections. There are ways around that, but the solution begins to start making Option 1 work like Option 2, so you might as well use Option 2.

I've seen a few solutions that create SQL Accounts to do the inital authentication for each user (via a single application based SQL account), then the rest works like Option 2 (again via a single application based SQL account). Those cases were using lots of SQL accounts, so each user could own a set of Views, and imitate Schemas. As Schemas & Aliases have been available since SQL Server 2005, it wouldn't be worthwhile to pick option 2 anymore for that reason.

Finally, don't use SQL Server Application roles either - they're bad security practice. Brian Kelly covers a few of the issues (pos & cons) in an article about them (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Security/sqlserversecurityprosandconsofapplicationroles/1116/).

Comment: Seems like option 2 with a standard profile will be best then, is there any standard approach or best practice as for how to best secure the users from an application level (rather than db level)?